# How do I SSH into a container running under WSL2 from Windows without Docker for Desktop

Tags: docker, wsl-2

I want to do demonstrate to the IT area at my work how one might use a container for isolated development.  I have installed WSL2, then I have a development container running with some basic developer tools--OpenJDK, etc.  I can SSH into the container from a WSL2 terminal simply by running `ssh user@172.17.0.2`, for example, but I cannot figure out how to SSH into this from Windows.  More importantly, I want to be able to SSH into the running container from Visual Studio Code via Windows, but things just seem to time out.  Does anybody know how to get this going?  I have a very locked-down IT environment and I want to do this without having to install Docker for Windows (which I doubt my IT department will ever approve).

Comment: Does [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2020/07/01/containers-wsl) helps you?

Comment: I think that still requires Docker for Desktop?  But I'll have a more detailed read, thanks.

I've had some luck simply adding `-p 23:22` to my `docker run` command, since then I can get to the container from Windows by running `ssh root@localhost -p 23`.  However, I'm still curious to know whether Windows can somehow be made aware of the IP address returned by `docker inspect`.